# how to add add external plugin(neptune) in chrome using external_extensions.json file

Tags: json, google-chrome, npapi, activexobject

i want add external plugin into chrome which run my external program,according to thishttps://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapiwe can add external plugin in chrome.I edited external_plugin.json file and and html code like this but still chrome saying plugin is not supported.I know in chrome NPAPI is being phased out.but they also says should only be used when no other approach will work.
i have no option than using chrome ,please help

```
{
"name": "npmeadax.dll",
 ...
 "plugins": [
  { "path": "C:\Program Files (x86)\MeadCo Neptune\npmeadax.dll" }
  ],
 ...
}

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadPage() {
        var lh = location.href;
        var embed = document.createElement('embed');
        embed.setAttribute('width','70%');
        embed.setAttribute('height','90%');
        embed.setAttribute('type','application/x-meadco-neptune-ax');
        embed.setAttribute('param-location',lh);
        var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        tbody.appendChild(embed);                
        try {

        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.run("C:/folderName/myfile.exe");

        }
        catch(e) {}
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this anymore; Chrome dropped support for NPAPI plugins completely in Chrome 45 (and for everyone who didn't override it in Chrome 42).